# How many data the NDEF payload can carry?

Tags: android, size, nfc, payload, ndef

The DOC of  google android said the ：payload byte array, containing zero to `(2 ** 32 - 1)` bytes,must not be null.
So I think a NDEF record can carry 4GB data.

But when I check the max size of Samsung‘s TecTiles with `ndef.getMaxSize()`
the size is just 716.

Why the TecTiles from samsung is not 4GB？I think any NFC tag which supported NDEF can carry 4GB data at most.

Comment: hum, let's see, ..., because 4GB cost money?

Comment: Size depends on the implementation of the NFC tag. NDEF records which is related to NFC but is not equal to NFC could contain that much data.. So the maximum amount depends on size NFC tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limiting factor on the size of NDEF messages is the capacity of the tag in most cases.

For example, it is possible in most operating systems to have a file that is 2GB in size. However, you cannot have a 2GB file on a 128MB drive, because the drive cannot hold 2GB. It does not matter that the OS limit is 2GB -- the drive physically cannot hold anything near that limit.

In this respect, you can think of an NFC tag as being a very very very very very small drive. The number of bytes supported by an NFC tag varies by tag, but frequently is 1KB or less.

Comment: OH!How simple answer, I'm stupid. Ha Ha sorry!